# how to change my code into landscape orientation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, screen-orientation

I have written some code for displaying a drop down list, but the code below is not working when I use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{}
```

on iPad.

Does anyone have any ideas how I may solve this problem?

My code :

```
- (void)dropDownCellSelected:(NSInteger)returnIndex{
    [button setTitle:[arrayData objectAtIndex:returnIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}   


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)){
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Help me to solve the problem on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```